# Getting error when calling connect as function in prepare statement

Tags: php

EDIT. My error ONLY occurs when calling database connection as a function, if I call my database connection normally, the error do not occur.

I'm trying to execute a prepare statement with database connection as a function so that it can be reused inside other functions. Executing normal SQL codes work when using database connection function but I'm getting errors when I try to use in a prepare statement.

This is my code.

```php
function connect(){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    return $conn;
}

if (connect()->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . connect()->connect_error);
} else {
    echo "GOOD";
}

$val = "1";
$stmt = connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$val);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
$stmt->close();
```

When connecting database as a normal variable such as this works.

```php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id = ?");
```

However, I get "Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool" whenever I tried to call my connection as a function.
What am I doing wrong with this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to a member function fetch\_assoc() on boolean in <path>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669088/call-to-a-member-function-fetch-assoc-on-boolean-in-path)

Comment: @LLJ97 I only get the error when I call my connection as a function. When I call it the normal way, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a while and based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52763537/mysqli-prepare-statement-error-mysql-server-has-gone-away), I was able fix my problem by declaring a variable for connection. However, this doesn't explain why directly calling connect doesn't work. Can somebody explain to me why the first way doesn't work?

```
$db = connect();
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id = ?");
```